# Create java recursive array list from records retrieve from database

Tags: java, database, recursion, arraylist

I am fetching records from database where each record has parent and child column and I am retrieving these records as an array List. Now I want to create recursive array list based on parent child relationship.

Suppose I am retrieving below List from database

```
Id  ParentId  Child Id
1       0       1
2       0       2
3       1       3
4       1       4
5       2       5
6       2       6
7       3       7
8       3       8
9       4       9
10      4       10
11      5       11
12      5       12
```

So First root node 0 has one child node as 1 which has as 3 ,4 childe nodes. 3 has 7 and 8 as child nodes and 4 has 9 and 10 as child nodes and so on...

Second root node 0 has one child node 2 which has 5 and 6 child nodes. 5 has 11 and 12 as child nodes and so on...

My Node class will be as below which I will convert to json array and display as tree in UI

```
public class Node {
    private int parentId;
    private int childId ;
    private List<Node> children = new ArrayList<Node>();

    public int getParentId() {
        return parentId;
    }
    public void setParentId(int parentId) {
        this.parentId = parentId;
    }
    public int getChildId() {
        return childId;
    }
    public void setChildId(int childId) {
        this.childId = childId;
    }
    public List<Node> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }
    public void setChildren(List<Node> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }
}
```

I want to create list of tree nodes like below 
There can be any number of root nodes and child nodes.

So First root node 0 has one child node as 1 which has as 3 ,4 childe nodes. 3 has 7 and 8 as child nodes and 4 has 9 and 10 as child nodes and so on...

Second root node 0 has one child node 2 which has 5 and 6 child nodes. 5 has 11 and 12 as child nodes and so on...

Comment: Okay and what do you need help with?

Comment: I want to create recursive tree node list from records retrieve from database. like parent 0 then their children and then their children and so on.. second parent 0 then their children and then their children and so on..

Comment: We get that part but this is a place for specific questions, not throw out an idea and make us do it for you.

Comment: I solved it with the help of recursive call !!! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Take reference from the below code : 

private static void createRecursiveList(ArrayList<MenuView> menuList)
    {
        MenuView mainMenuView = null;
        ArrayList<MenuView> mainMenuList = new ArrayList<MenuView>();

        int index = 0;

        for(MenuView menuView : menuList)
        {
            if(menuView.getParentId() == 0)
            {
                ArrayList<MenuView> childMenuList = new ArrayList<MenuView>();
                findChildIndex(index, menuList, childMenuList);

                if(childMenuList.size() > 0)
                    mainMenuList.add(childMenuList.get(0));
                else
                {
                    mainMenuView = new MenuView(menuView.getId(), menuView.getMenuName(), menuView.getParentId(), menuView.getOrder(), childMenuList);          
                    mainMenuList.add(mainMenuView);
                }
            }               

            index++;
        }

        printRecursiveList(mainMenuList);
    }


    private static void findChildIndex(int parentIndex, ArrayList<MenuView> menuList, ArrayList<MenuView> childMenuList)
    {
        MenuView mView = null;
        List<Integer> childIdxList = getChildIndex(parentIndex, menuList);

        if(childIdxList.size() > 0)
        {
            ArrayList<MenuView> childMenuLst = new ArrayList<MenuView>();

            for(Integer parentIdx : childIdxList)
            {
                findChildIndex(parentIdx, menuList, childMenuLst);

                if(!hasChilds(parentIdx, menuList))
                {
                    mView = new MenuView(menuList.get(parentIdx).getId(), menuList.get(parentIdx).getMenuName(), menuList.get(parentIdx).getParentId(), menuList.get(parentIdx).getOrder(), new ArrayList<MenuView>());// menuList.get(parentIdx).getChilds());
                    childMenuLst.add(mView);
                }
            }

            mView = new MenuView(menuList.get(parentIndex).getId(), menuList.get(parentIndex).getMenuName(), menuList.get(parentIndex).getParentId(), menuList.get(parentIndex).getOrder(), childMenuLst);
            childMenuList.add(mView);

        }
    }


    private static List<Integer> getChildIndex(int parentIndex, ArrayList<MenuView> menuList)
       {
           List<Integer> childIdxList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
           int index = 0;

           int parentId = menuList.get(parentIndex).getId();

           for(MenuView menuView : menuList)
           {
               if(menuView.getParentId() == parentId)
                   childIdxList.add(index);

               index ++;
           }       

           return childIdxList;
       }

    private static boolean hasChilds(int parentIndex, ArrayList<MenuView> menuList)
    {
        int parentId = menuList.get(parentIndex).getId();

        for(MenuView menuView : menuList)
        {
           if(menuView.getParentId() == parentId)
               return true;
        }

        return false;
    }


    private static void printRecursiveList(ArrayList<MenuView> mainMenuList)
    {
        int i = 0;

        System.out.println("Size of final list : "+mainMenuList.size()+"\n\n");

        while(i < mainMenuList.size())
        {
            System.out.println((i+1)+">>>> "+mainMenuList.get(i).toString());
            i++;
        }
    }
```